# Python os.path.isdir is True but os.listdir yields "No such file or directory"

Tags: python

My python script raises an error on `os.listdir` but `os.path.isdir` indicates that the target location is indeed a path:

```py
import os
path = '/Volumes/WD Elements/photofix/organized-photos/2003'
os.path.isdir(path) # => True
os.listdir(path) # => OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Volumes/WD Elements/photofix/organized-photos/2003'
```

When I `ls` the path on bash, the command succeeds without error:

```sh
ls '/Volumes/WD Elements/photofix/organized-photos/2003'
echo $? # => 0
ls -ld '/Volumes/WD Elements/photofix/organized-photos/2003'
# => drwxr-xr-x  29 JellicleCat  staff  986 Apr  4 22:19 /Volumes/WD Elements/photofix/organized-photos/2003
```

Is this indicative of a Python bug? A hardware failure? An OS bug?

*Python 2.7.16 on MacOS High Sierra*

Comment: This does look like it may be a bug, unfortunately you are using python 2.7 which is no longer supported so there's nowhere to submit the bug report to. If your code is compatible go up to python 3.x and run the code. The only other thing it could be is based on the name if it is a symlink to a folder that may not work, but I am not sure.

Comment: At the very least, you should test using Python 2.7.18 (which was the final release). If that doesn't fix the problem, test with the latest version of Python 3 so you can confirm it's a bug in Python 2.

Comment: Could you post the output of `ls -ld` on the path so we can see what it actually is?

Comment: `no such file or directory` might actually mean `I do not have rights to read there, but I will not tell you that the directory exists to not leak information`. Not sure python 2.7 works like that, but it's worth checking this.

Comment: On some 2.7 versions python had problems showing data of symlinks with `os.listdir()`, maybe this is the problem

Comment: @D-E-N thanks. The path in question is not a symlink, though.

Comment: @wjandrea thanks. Here's the output of `ls -ld` (the directory is empty): `drwxr-xr-x  29 JellicleCat  staff  986 Apr  4 22:19 /Volumes/WD Elements/photofix/organized-photos/2003`

Comment: @Guillaume thanks. I do have write permissions as well as read permissions. I've updated my post to show the output of `ls -ld`

Comment: Is it just that directory or all directories in that volume or all directories everywhere on your computer?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi that directory and a handful of others behave this way, but most of the directories beneath `/Volumes/WD Elements/photofix/organized-photos` do not result in this error.

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon the exact same problem, whith triggered the following error message:

```
[ERROR]FileNotFoundError raised while getting the package builder: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
```

The following script is a minimal working example that reproduced the error.

```
import os

some_dir = "C:\<WHATEVER PATH IS CAUSING YOU GRIEF>"
some_dir = os.path.normpath(some_dir)
print(f'some_dir: {some_dir}')
if os.path.exists(some_dir):
    some_dir_files = os.listdir(some_dir)
    print(f"files: {','.join(some_dir_files)}")
```

After some digging, I've noticed that a) `some_dir` was pointing to a symlink to a dir, b) the symlink was missing some permissions.

Comment: Neato! Next time I get access to my machine, I'll see if my cause is the same